# Servicio Windows desaparecido tras reinicio

Tags: servicio, windows7

Tengo un computador con Windows 7 el cual posee instalado un Servicio Windows que he programado en VB.NET y que ha estado funcionando de manera normal durante bastante tiempo.

Hace unos días atrás dicho computador fue reiniciado automáticamente a través de una tarea programada, reinicio que se realizó sin problemas aparentes.
Sin embargo, horas después noté que el Servicio Windows señalado ya no estaba presente en el listado de servicios de Windows (services.msc), pero extrañamente, el servicio Windows aún estaba en el listado de programas, y también estaba el ejecutable correspondiente en el directorio donde estaba instalado este servicio Windows.
Tuve que efectuar la carga manual del servicio Windows en este listado de servicios Windows (con la aplicación sc.exe y el comando create), y de ahí pude poner en ejecución nuevamente el servicio.

He revisado los eventos de Windows para verificar si había algún antecedente al respecto, sin embargo, no encuentro nada de interés.

¿Existe algo adicional que pueda revisar y que me permita entender por qué pasó esta situación?

Comment: ya miriastes : claves de registro windows 7 ? ami en el pasado me paso algo similar (se me reiniciaba sola la compu pero tenia windows 8 y ps mire en el claves de registro windows  y ahi estaba el error :) o quiza es un virus ya mirastes con tu antivirus :)

Comment: hola @simon, a que te refieres con clave de registro de Windows? Si es que es original? Estuve mirando el antivirus (Avast), y la última vez que se detectó algo fue 3 días antes de esto

Comment: podrias  compartir el reporte de tu antivirus?